# Find transitive sub-relations of a non-transitive relation

Tags: relation-algebra, relations

Given a relation $R$ that is not transitive, I want to find subsets of $R$ that are actually transitive. What is the name of this operation and how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Well order $R = \{ a_{xi} : xi <|R| \}$.  Let $R_0$ = $R$.  Given $R_{xi} \subseteq R$,
define $R_{(xi+1)} = R_{xi} - \{ a_{xi} \}$ if $R_{xi}$ isn't transitive, $= R_{xi}$ otherwise.
For limit ordinal $\eta$ with for all $xi < \eta$, $R_{xi}$ is defined, define, 
$R_{\eta} = \bigcap{ R_x : xi < \eta }$.  $R_{|R|}$ is a transitive subset of $R$.

Comment: How do we obtain such order?

Comment: @orezvani.  If R is uncountabe, then use AxC to well order R.  IF

Comment: @orezvani.  If R is uncountabe, then use AxC to well order R.  If R is countable then use the bijection between R and a set of integers > 0 to well order R.  For a quick  and easy transitive subset grab the empty relation or a singleton of R.  Transitive closers are more useful and much easier to construct.